# STL container equivalent of Delphi set?

Tags: c++, delphi, stl

Is there an STL container with functionality similar to the Delphi "set", the code below taken from DelphiBasics:

```
type
    TDigits = set of '1'..'9';       // Set of numeric digit characters
var
    digits : TDigits;                // Set variable
    myChar : char;
begin
    digits := ['2', '4'..'7'];

    // Now we can test to see what we have set on:
    for myChar := '1' to '9' do
        begin
        if (myChar In digits) then
            DoSomething()
        else
            DoSomethingElse();
        end;
end;
```

Comment: Vote down? Wow...you could at least leave a comment...I'm here to learn.

Comment: Three close votes for "unclear what you're asking." Unless the voters don't know Delphi - in which case how can they judge? - it's a very clear question, with good example code that demonstrates the usage of the type you want an equivalent of. Bizarre.

Comment: @DavidM: Agreed, very bizarre. SO is a great site overall, but I think the mad chase for reputation can skew decision-making towards the snappy end of the scale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest equivalent to Delphi's `set of` is the STL `std::bitset` container in the `<bitset>` header.

Similarities:

- You can set its range in the beginning;
- `std::bitset::set` is equal to `Include()` in Delphi;
- `std::bitset::reset` is equal to `Exclude()` in Delphi;
- `std::bitset::test()` is equal to `in` in Delphi;
- You can use bitwise operators (`|`, `&`, `<<`, `>>`, `^`, etc).

Differences:

- In Delphi, the maximum size of a `set` is 256 bits, so if you want to create a larger set you have to use something like `array [1..N] of set of byte`.  In C++, `std::bitset` does not have that limitation;
- In Delphi, `set` bits are included/excluded by value. In C++, `std::bitset` bits are set/reset by index.